# How to create a object to post score?

Tags: android, metadata, facebook-opengraph

I'm developing a game on Android and want to integrate with facebook, so user can share his results.

I'm using the Open Graph to create the actions, the objects and so on from my app.

Already done some progress using direct Graph API requests like this.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("my_object", "http://samples.ogp.me/251143638264597" );
mAsyncRunner.request("me/MY_APP_NAMESPACE:beat", params, "POST",
new WallPostRequestListener(), null);
```

This way the post is made. But ,as you can see on the code above, i'm using the sample object created by Open Graph.

My problem is: how can i create an object dynamically, in java? It's possible? I've already tried to create a JSON object, but didn't have success.
I saw on the tutorials an HTML metadata, but this is the only way to do it?